# Difference between Windows Task Scheduler Task Trigger time and LastRuntime fetched from Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\" | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | Select TASKNAME,LastRunTime|where{$_.TaskName -eq "FIN_400"}|tee-object -variable tsjobtime
```

I am fetching the LastRuntime of a Task from Windows Task Scheduler using the above commands in a PowerShell script but the value fetched is not always tallying with the Value displayed in the Task Scheduler.

For example, from the History of Windows Task Scheduler, Task Start/Trigger time is shownn as 11.30:00 but from the PowerShell script when i am fetching the data LastRunTime, I am sometimes getting a value 11.30:15 or 11.30:22

Is the Task Trigger Time or Start Time same as LastRuntime fetched?